Swiftdata get-error (Thread 6: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cc165d0c)) -issues when inserting a new swiftdata
When I do the classic modelcontext.insert(myModel) everything works fine. But since I want at the same time initialize a local notification using myModels UUID as the identifier the app crashes. Now, I tried out not initializing the notification directly, just reading the UUID.uuidstring when viewing the newly inserted myModel. But it cannot fetch the UUID (the variable is called objectID in my case), it only crashes. Why?
The error is:

Thread 6: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cc165d0c

My model:
@Model
final class HomeObject: ObservableObject {    
    let objectID: UUID = UUID()
    var objectType: ObjectType?
    var room: String?
    var roomPictogram: RoomPictograms?
    var dateOfPurchase: Date?
    var checkTimeInterval: Int?
    var lastChecked: Date?
    var checkDate: Date?
    var replacementDate: Date?
    var home: Home?
    
    init(objectType: ObjectType?, room: String?, roomPictogram: RoomPictograms?, dateOfPurchase: Date? = nil, checkTimeInterval: Int?, lastChecked: Date?, checkDate: Date?, replacementDate: Date?, home: Home?) {
        self.objectType = objectType
        self.room = room
        self.roomPictogram = roomPictogram
        self.dateOfPurchase = dateOfPurchase
        self.checkTimeInterval = checkTimeInterval
        self.lastChecked = lastChecked
        self.checkDate = checkDate
        self.replacementDate = replacementDate
        self.home = home        
    }
}

And the code for saving the model:
func addItem(_ homes: [Home], _ modelContext: ModelContext, _ dismiss: DismissAction) {        
    var replacementDate: Date = .now
    
    if dateOfPurchaseBool == false {
        dateOfPurchase = .now
        replacementDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(findReplaceTimeInterval(objectType))
    } else {
        replacementDate = dateOfPurchase.addingTimeInterval(findReplaceTimeInterval(objectType))
    }
    
    let checkTimeInterval = findTimeInterval(objectType)
    var checkDate: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.month = checkTimeInterval
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: .now)!
    }
    
    let newObject = HomeObject(objectType: objectType, room: objectPlacement, roomPictogram: roomImage, dateOfPurchase: dateOfPurchase, checkTimeInterval: checkTimeInterval, lastChecked: .now, checkDate: checkDate, replacementDate: replacementDate, home: findHome(HomeViewModel().selectedHome!, homes))
    
    modelContext.insert(newObject)
    modelContext.insert(RoomModel(rooms: objectPlacement))
    
    let timeintervalMonth = checkDate.timeIntervalSinceNow + 100
        
     Task {
         var localNotification = LocalNotification(identifier: newObject.objectID.uuidString,
                                                          title: "Time to check",
                                                          body: "\(objectType) in \(objectPlacement)",
                                                          timeInterval: timeintervalMonth,
                                                          repeats: false)
         localNotification.subtitle = ""
         localNotification.bundleImageName = ""
         localNotification.userInfo = ["nextView" : NextView.homeObjectDetailView.rawValue]
         localNotification.userInfoMoode = ["object" : newObject.objectID.uuidString]
         localNotification.categoryIdentifier = "snooze"
         await NotificationViewModel().schedule(localNotification: localNotification, newObject)
     }
                  
     dismiss()        
}

When the app is crashing this is what i get underneath the UUID variable:
{
@storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _objectID)
init(initialValue) {
    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.objectID, to: initialValue)
    _objectID = _SwiftDataNoType()
}
get {
    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.objectID)
    return self.getValue(forKey: \.objectID)
}
set {
    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.objectID) {
        self.setValue(forKey: \.objectID, to: newValue)
    }
}

}
